Trying to pip instal wget with cmd
I am trying to install wget with pip through the following commands:
C:\Users\jacob>pip uninstall wget
Found existing installation: wget 3.2
Uninstalling wget-3.2:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\wget-3.2.dist-info\*
    c:\users\jacob\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages\wget.py
Proceed (Y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled wget-3.2

C:\Users\jacob>pip install wget
Collecting wget
  Using cached wget-3.2-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: wget
Successfully installed wget-3.2

C:\Users\jacob>where wget
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

C:\Users\jacob>wget
'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


I tried to install wget from this link, but the executable file it downloaded won't execute. As a new programmer, I am quite lost in the world of computers. Any help would be appreciated!

instead of running wget directly, try python -m wget. If that doesn't work, try python3 -m wget.

pip installs python module, not a CLI command. You can use it as python -m wget <url>.
Or  you can install wget command from http://www.gnu.org/software/wget

It looks like you're using Windows. I recommend that you check UnxUtils which, according to themselves, are "native Win32 ports of some GNU utilities", including wget.
Once you download it (from SourceForge, for instance), extract UnxUtils.zip\usr\local\wbin\wget.exe to some folder and add such folder to PATH environment variable (or extract wget.exe to C:\Windows\System32 directly). Then, you should be able to use wget.exe from any new terminal window.
Note that wget is a command-line application, so if you just double-click it, it will mostly just open and close a terminal real quick, informing that you have not provided the necessary arguments.

Instead of install wget from python is not something I have heard of before, honestly. Perhaps the wget module you are installing is a python remake or something. Either way, run it as python module with the -m flag:
python(3) -m wget.
Or just install it the way any other person would. I am pretty sure that the link you tried to install it from is not official. The official link, at least for windows, is here. Download the setup package and run it. Then try running wget from cmd.exe (or terminal, choose your windows version). If you are downloading from the website, note your windows version. That might be the reason you couldn't install it from the link you provided. Happy coding!
